# Branch Sharesheetstyle design

Tags: branch.io

I am working on a project with Branch. I want to change the default design of sharesheet to a customized design. I found this code in the documents,

```
ShareSheetStyle shareSheetStyle = new ShareSheetStyle(MainActivity.this, "Check this out!", "This stuff is awesome:")
                    .setCopyUrlStyle(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_send), "Copy", "Added to clipboard")
                    .setMoreOptionStyle(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search), "Show more")
                    .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.FACEBOOK)
                    .addPreferredSharingOption(SharingHelper.SHARE_WITH.EMAIL)
                    .setAsFullWidthStyle(true)
                    .setSharingTitle("Share With");
```

But I just can change the icon and text. How could I have a customized design and also be able to track the sharing data.

Answer (score 0):

The Sharesheet that is provided by the Branch SDK is built on the native share sheet, which cannot be customised. If you would like to build a custom share experience, you'll need to generate the link beforehand using the SDK and then pass that into your custom share sheet.

You can track the data for these links by going into Sources tab and filtering as per **feature=Share**.